# ThreadPoolExecutor - Can I throw exception if pool is full

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

Is it possible to throw exception if incoming request can't be handled?

So, I have some fixed thread pool:

```
private val executor: ThreadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4) as ThreadPoolExecutor
```

And I don't want requests go to thread queue if can't be handled, I just want to throw exception.

I'm trying to check activeCount and throw exception if is greater than max pool size but it's not working just like I want.

```
private fun checkPoolSize() {
    if (executor.activeCount >= 4) {
        throw RuntimeException("Request can't be handled. ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution for this is to use a queue of capacity 0 and `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy` as a `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

The static methods in `Executors` do not expose the full set of parameters you want for this, so you will need to instantiate a `ThreadPoolExecutor` directly. In your case, you could use the following:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,                                     /* Core pool size                    */
                       4,                                     /* Max pool size                     */
                       0, TimeUnit.SECONDS,                   /* Core th. keep-alive               */
                       new MyQueue<Runnable>(0),              /* No queueing allowed               */
                       Executors.defaultThreadFactory(),      /* default                           */
                       new AbortPolicy())                     /* throws when all core threads busy */
```

**A few notes:**

- 0 seconds (3rd and 4th arguments) correspond to the core thread keep-alive time. Setting 0 means your core threads will never be stopped even if they remain idle. This is the default behaviour when using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`.
- `Executors.defaultThreadFactory()` is the default thread factory, same as when using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`.
- Here core and max thread pool size is set to 4 (1st and 2nd argument), which for your use case seems appropriate.
- `MyQueue` is an implementation of `BlockingQueue` which accepts 0 as a capacity (i.e. which can only be empty. This is of course not a queue but implementing this allows to seamlessly integrating with the `ThreadPoolExecutor` provided by the JDK.).

**Further consideration**:

With such fine-tuning of your thread pool, beware that the throughput will be limited. Here, considering 4 threads and an average latency `L` in seconds for the tasks submitted to the thread pool, the average throughput allowed by this configuration is `4/L` tasks/second.

Comment: This is solution which I looking for, but I have to create own implementation of BlockingQueue because LinkedBlockingQueue throws IllegalArgumentException if capacity argument is <= 0.

Comment: @DamianU Ah right, sorry I thought it would accept it.

Comment: @DamianU you don’t need to implement your own queue, [`SynchronousQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a saturation policy which comes in play when your bounded queue fills up. You can set a saturation policy by calling `setRejectedExecutionHandler()` of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The out-of-the-box implementations are `AbortPolicy`, `CallerRunsPolicy`, `DiscardPolicy` and `DiscardOldestPolicy`. `AbortPolicy` is default which throws `RejectedExecutionException` when the bounded queue fills up. You can also provide your own custom implementation.